# Define of Oracle LONG_RAW column fails in 11g with ORA-01062

Tags: sql, oracle

I inherited the support of a small application that originally used Oracle 9. It is a basically a system to store and retrieve photographs in Oracle as LONG_RAW columns. The size of the photos range from 20k to over 4 meg. Everything works fine in Oracle 9.

I upgraded the database to Oracle 11g, and am having trouble reading some of the larger photos. The define statement for a LONG_RAW column holding a photo much larger than (I think) 100k fails with an ORA-01062 - unable to allocate memory for define buffer.

I spent all day yesterday googling this and the two most prevalent answers were:

1. do a piece wise fetch
2. increase the maximum buffer size

But alas, even more googling could not find how to do either one of these.

I think I could fix this if I could find where the maximum Oracle buffer size is set. I looked at all the .ora files I could find, but no joy.

I am stuck big time. Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you reading the `LONG RAW`?  Any chance of converting to a `BLOB`?  `LONG RAW` isn't supported any longer.

Comment: Please [edit] you question with a [MRE] including: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement for your table; the DML (`INSERT`) statement or procedure/function you are using to insert the image; and the full text of the error.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that LONG RAW isn't supported any longer. I used the to_lob function to convert the LONG_RAW columns to BLOBS. But the photos have checksums and the conversion destroyed them on some of the smaller LONG_RAWs, and all of the larger ones. I was able to read the BLOBs but they failed the checksum test. I am reading them with "select * from photoTable where id = 'somekey". Nothing fancy.